VS Code shortcut to force `git` to add a file
How do I make a shortcut in VS Code to force git to add a file? EG I keep *.png in .gitignore so image files are ignored, but sometimes I want to add an image file so I can include it in README.md. I can do that EG with git add -f ./dir_name/image.png. Is it possible to make this into a keyboard shortcut in VS Code?

Add this to your keybindings.json:
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+a",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
            "text": "git add -f ${relativeFile}\u000D"
        }
    },

Explanation: when you press "shift+alt+a", what follows after "text" in "args" is sent to the terminal. VS Code will replace ${relativeFile} with the relative path to the currently active file. \u000D is the code for a carriage return ("ENTER key"), which effectively "presses enter" after sending the text to the terminal. Without \u000D, the command will be sent to the terminal but will not run, instead it will wait for you to focus the terminal and press enter.
Sources:

VS Code docs - Terminal Basics
VS Code docs - Terminal Advanced
VS Code docs - Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code
Virtual-Key Codes (including 0x0D)
VS Code docs - Variables Reference (including ${relativeFile})
Stack Overflow - Answer to "Shortcut for running terminal command in VS code"
Stack Overflow - Answer to "Bind a keypress to a shell command that uses the current file in visual studio code"


won't relativeFile fial if the integrated terminal has had its cwd changed to anything other than the default- the workspace folder?

Yes, you're right. This isn't a problem for me because I typically only use consoles whose current directory is the workspace folder (or if I change directory then I kill the console afterwards). You could fix this by using ${file} instead of ${relativeFile} which would use an absolute path, but it's important to me that the paths that are displayed are readable, and I find relative paths more readable than absolute paths.
